# como hacer un input type radio en jade?

Tags: jade

Archivo save.jave

```
extends ../layout
block content
 h1 Guardar usuarios
  form(method="post", action="#{action}")
    label Nombre
    br
    input(type="text",name="nombre",required="required", value="#    {programmers.nombre}")
    br
    label Apellido
    br
    input(type="text",name="apellido",required="required", value="#{programmers.apellido}")
    br
    label Nombre usuario
    br
    input(type="text",name="user",required="required", value="#{programmers.user}")
    br
    label contraseña
    br
    input(type="password",name="pass",required="required", value="#{programmers.pass}")
    br
    label edad
    br
    input(type="text",name="edad",required="required", value="#{programmers.edad}")
    br
    label genero
    br
    input.with-gap(type='radio', class='radioSpans', id='test1', name='genero' , masculino='masculino') 
    Thing masculino <br>
    input.with-gap(type='radio', class='radioSpans', id='test2',name='genero', value='femenino') 
    Thing femenino <br>
    br
    input(type="submit", value="guardar")
    a(href='/app/programmers') Cancelar
```

no se por que no me muestra los input type radio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cómo es el html que te genera? Aunque tiene más pinta de ser un problema de estilos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con :

```
input(type="radio", name="genero", value="1", checked=genero=="masculino")
Thing masculino <br>
input(type="radio", name="genero", value="0", checked=genero=="femenino")
Thing femenino<br>
```

Tambien `checked` lo va a marcar si es que tu formulario necesita o tiene que recibir informacion

Ademas te dejo un link bastante interesante en donde escribes codigo `javascript` o `html` y te muestra el equivalente para `jada`

[Jade converter](http://html2jade.org/)

Comment: igual no aparece el circulo para chekear

Comment: puedes inspeccionar elemento y ver si genera un `radio`, quita tus clases quizas puede haber un problema ahi

Comment: ni el `value` ni el `checked` son necesarios para que dibuje los `radiobuttons`, puedes poner solamente `<input type="radio">`, casi seguro que es cosa de estilos.

Comment: @blonfu al parecer en su caso si es  necesario, ya que los demas datos esperan un value de `programmers`. Debe ser netamente un problema de estilo, por eso saque las clases en mi respuesta

Comment: para que funcione el formulario seguramente pero no para que se vean los radiobuttons

Comment: exacto, solo lo agregue para que entendiera que tambien faltaba ese tag en caso que quisiera llenarlo, tambien especifique el porque en mi respuesta

Comment: No me había fijado en tu comentario de que quitara las clases, justo estaba yo escribiendo el mio ;)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta un value por confirmar, encontre esto.

```
input(type="radio", name="genero", value="1", checked=gender=="masculino")
| Male
input(type="radio", name="genero", value="0", checked=gender=="femenino")
| Female
```

Revisa este link:
[Jade radio button checked condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624650/jade-radio-button-checked-condition)

Comment: igual no aparece el circulo para chekear